# Windows: Installing pg gem fail with "Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)" and "undefined reference to `PQconnectdb'"

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rubygems

I'm having troubling installing the pg gem on Windows 10.

I've looked around and was able to progress with the first set of errors, but now am stuck with the error shown below.

Most answers I found all are for Linux and OSX and usually revolve around installing libpq-dev,which I'm not able to find for Windows. Given that I've moved past the initial missing libpq-fe.h error, I'm assuming that the required dev files are already included in the Windows installer.

I've tried specifying the folder/lib locations several ways, including:

`gem install pg -v '1.1' -- --with-pg-dir="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13" --with-pq-dir="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13"`

and

`gem install pg -v '1.1' -- --with-pg-config="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_config.exe"`

But neither seem to work. Any suggestions?

Additional info:

**Console output**

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-config=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_config.exe'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.1.0/ext
C:/Ruby30/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20210424-18200-bi9e9l.rb extconf.rb --with-pg-config\=C:\\Program\ Files\\PostgreSQL\\13\\bin\\pg_config.exe
Using config values from C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_config.exe
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

**mkmf.log**

```
"i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong     -lmsvcrt-ruby300  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return !!argv[argc];
8: }
/* end */

"i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong     -lmsvcrt-ruby300  -Wl,-rpath,C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- yes

"i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <libpq-fe.h>
/* end */

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... -------------------- yes

"i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <libpq/libpq-fs.h>
/* end */

--------------------

find_header: checking for pg_config_manual.h... -------------------- yes

"i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <pg_config_manual.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... -------------------- no

"i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-rpath,C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib     -lmsvcrt-ruby300 -lpq  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
C:/Ruby30/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Temp\cch5p7v1.o:conftest.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `PQconnectdb'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 6: 
 7: /*top*/
 8: extern int t(void);
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
13:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
14:   }
15: 
16:   return !!argv[argc];
17: }
18: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return !p; }
/* end */

"i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-rpath,C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib     -lmsvcrt-ruby300 -lpq  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c:18:13: error: conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'
   18 | extern void PQconnectdb();
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from conftest.c:5:
C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include/libpq-fe.h:264:16: note: previous declaration of 'PQconnectdb' was here
  264 | extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 6: 
 7: /*top*/
 8: extern int t(void);
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
13:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
14:   }
15: 
16:   return !!argv[argc];
17: }
18: extern void PQconnectdb();
19: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... -------------------- no

"i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-rpath,C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib     -lmsvcrt-ruby300 -llibpq  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
C:/Ruby30/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4PD9EV.o:conftest.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `PQconnectdb'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 6: 
 7: /*top*/
 8: extern int t(void);
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
13:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
14:   }
15: 
16:   return !!argv[argc];
17: }
18: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return !p; }
/* end */

"i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-rpath,C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib     -lmsvcrt-ruby300 -llibpq  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c:18:13: error: conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'
   18 | extern void PQconnectdb();
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from conftest.c:5:
C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include/libpq-fe.h:264:16: note: previous declaration of 'PQconnectdb' was here
  264 | extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 6: 
 7: /*top*/
 8: extern int t(void);
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
13:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
14:   }
15: 
16:   return !!argv[argc];
17: }
18: extern void PQconnectdb();
19: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... -------------------- no

"i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-rpath,C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib     -lmsvcrt-ruby300 -lms/libpq  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
C:/Ruby30/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lms/libpq
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 6: 
 7: /*top*/
 8: extern int t(void);
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
13:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
14:   }
15: 
16:   return !!argv[argc];
17: }
18: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return !p; }
/* end */

"i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-rpath,C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/lib     -lmsvcrt-ruby300 -lms/libpq  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c:18:13: error: conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'
   18 | extern void PQconnectdb();
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from conftest.c:5:
C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/include/libpq-fe.h:264:16: note: previous declaration of 'PQconnectdb' was here
  264 | extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 6: 
 7: /*top*/
 8: extern int t(void);
 9: int main(int argc, char **argv)
10: {
11:   if (argc > 1000000) {
12:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
13:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
14:   }
15: 
16:   return !!argv[argc];
17: }
18: extern void PQconnectdb();
19: int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: Upon further inspection of the log file, it seems that the installer is finding libpq, but throwing this error: ```conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'```. Looking through online this seems to be fixed by setting ```sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"``` before installing the gem. However, this solution only is applicable to unix systems. Any thoughts on how to achieve this on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was apparently being caused because I was using the 32 bit version of Ruby. Installed the 64 bit and the issue was resolved.